# Why are the arrows in the chemical equation not full arrows?

Tags: equations, arrows, chemistry

I have the following code:

```
\begin{equation}

   \ce e^- + ^{40}_{19}K -> ^{40}_{18}Ar^* + \Pgne -> ^{40}_{18}Ar + \Pgne + \gamma

\end{equation}
```

but in my document `->` is not connected for a full arrow. [image: Wrong arrows]

I have:

```
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\usepackage[italic]{hepnames}
```

in my document.

So i'm wondering what is wrong.

I have tried adding `{}` around the equation ( `{` is before `e^-` and `}` is after `\gamma`)
but it looks like this: [image: Also wrong] which is even worse.

Comment: First of all, start with removing the empty lines in the `equation` environment. You should get an error message from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the empty lines in the `equation` environment, place the whole chemical equation inside of the argument of `\ce` and surround `\Pgne` by  a set of `{}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[italic]{hepnames}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   \ce {e^- + ^{40}_{19}K -> ^{40}_{18}Ar^* + {\Pgne} -> ^{40}_{18}Ar + {\Pgne} + \gamma}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Added {} like you said and that fixed it, thanks!

Comment: @MarcusJohnson that is the documented escape mechanism for input `mhchem` doesn't know what to do with